# ExtJS Console Error

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've received this error `TypeError: h is undefined` in console.This error is apply after add new item after edit page and exists Library List with many items.I'm using ExtJS 3.4
I've tried few versions but without any result.This is image about error

[image]

This is my code for setup library list

```
       this.libraryListGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            columns: [
                {
                    header: '',
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    width: 33,
                    dataIndex: '',
                    fixed: true,
                    renderer: this.renderOrder
                },
                {
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    editable: !this.config.viewOnly,
                    editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
                        allowBlank: true,
                        controllerThis: this,
                        autoCreate: {tag: 'input', type: 'text', maxlength: '10'},
                        listeners: {
                            blur: function(item){
                                var record = item.getValue();
                                record = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(record);
                                item.setValue(record);
                            },
                            render: function(cmp)
                            {
                                cmp.getEl().on('click',function(){
                                    this.dom.focus();
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }),
                    header: 'Library',
                    id: 'name'
                },
                {
                    header: '',
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    width: 35,
                    dataIndex: '',
                    fixed: true,
                    renderer: this.renderActions
                }
            ]
        }),
        ds: this.libraryListDataStore,
        height: 200,
        width: 'auto',
        allowEdit: true,
        listeners: {
            rowclick: {
                fn: onRowClick,
                scope: this
            }
        },
        forceValidation: true,
        loadMask: true,
        renderTo: 'libraryListGrid',
        stripeRows: true,
        tbar: [{
            disabled: this.config.viewOnly,
            text: "Add ",
            icon: '/images/ext-gantt/add.png',
            handler : function(){
                // access the Record constructor through the grid's store
                var LibraryListSize = this.libraryListGrid.getStore().data.length;
                var Plant = this.libraryListGrid.getStore().recordType;
                var p = new Plant({
                });
                this.libraryListGrid.stopEditing();
                this.libraryListDataStore.insert(LibraryListSize, p);
                this.libraryListGrid.startEditing(LibraryListSize, 1);
            },
            scope: this
        }],
        view:this.view


    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.libraryListGrid` doesn't exist in the scope of the handler.  Use `Ext.getCmp()` to grab the grid.

Comment: Or save your context before, like var self = this; before declaring this.libraryListGrid.